# How to create a notification class in vala

Tags: gtk, glib, vala

Im learning vala language and I want to create a service to trigger a notification.
Thats my code

```
public class Services.Notifications : Glib.Object {
  

  public void sendNotification (string title, string body,string icon_name, GLib.NotificationPriority priority) {
      var notification = new Notification (title);
      notification.set_body (body);
      notification.set_icon (new ThemedIcon (icon_name));
      notification.set_priority (priority);

      send_notification ("com.github.andirsun.myapp", notification);
  }
}
```

But Im facing this error

```
class Notifications: null
base type `null' of class `Services.Notifications' is not an object type
```

I added the file Services/Notification.vala in the meson.build file bit no works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your base class's name - `Glib.Object` should be `GLib.Object` (note the upper-case `L`)